# Dump database with pg_dump, ignoring tables that we don't have access to

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, database-dump

I have a script where `pg_dump` is failing with a message like this:

```
pg_dump -h db1 --format plain --encoding UTF8 --schema=public --schema-only --no-owner me
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation notmytable
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public.notmytable IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

This is causing the whole dump to abort.

Is there a way to either:

- Ignore tables that aren't owned by our user?
- Ignore errors?

I really don't want these tables in the dump, so even if we could get access to them, that wouldn't exactly solve the problem.

(Postgres 9.6.3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't appear there is a standard way to do this, but using the `--exclude-table` flag, we can use a workaround:

```
export EXCLUDETABLE=$(psql -t -h $HOST -d $DBNAME -c "select '--exclude-table=' || string_agg(tablename,' --exclude-table=') FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE tableowner NOT LIKE 'myuser';" )
```

This sets EXCLUDETABLE to look like `--exclude-table=foo --exclude-table=blah`

Now we pass that to `pg_dump`:

```
echo Excluding these tables from dump: $EXCLUDETABLE
pg_dump -h $HOST --format plain --encoding UTF8 --schema=public --schema-only --no-owner $EXCLUDETABLE $DBNAME > public-schema.sql
```